# Change of ContactsContract.RawContacts _ID after aggregation

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, rawcontacts

According to Google docs, you should use `LOOKUP_KEY` to fetch a contact, since its ID in the ContactsContract.Contacts table can change:

> An opaque value that contains hints on how to find the contact if its
>   row id changed as a result of a sync or aggregation.
>   ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY))

Is it also possible that a RawContacts's ID in the ContactsContract.RawContacts change as well?